# g++ not detecting gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk3, g++

I have installed gtkmm using `apt-get install libgtkmm-3.0-dev`. When I try to compile using `g++ test.cpp  'pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags  --libs'`, I get error saying `g++: error: pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags  --libs: No such file or directory`. I already searched about this none of them helped me.

Ubuntu version:20.04

Comment: What you actually want is `g++ test.cpp $(pkg-config ...)`

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
g++ test.cpp -o testexec `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your command, maybe it's a typo. Your mistake:

```bsh
g++ test.cpp  'pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags  --libs'
              ^                                     ^
```

You should use backticks ( ` ) instead single quotes ( ' ). So, the resulting command will be:

```bsh
g++ test.cpp  `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags  --libs`
```

You can also execute this: (This won't work in `Makefile` as make treats any texts inside `$(` and `)` as variable)

```bsh
g++ test.cpp  $(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags  --libs)
```

Any text place inside two backticks is executed as command and output is placed is command ( `$(` and `)` will give same results) . Assume you executed this command:

```bsh
echo `which echo`
```

Here text inside backticks is `which echo` . It is executed, and it outputs `/bin/echo` . So, the resulting command will be:

```bsh
echo /bin/echo
```